# PYTHON 3.6.0 & DJANGO 3.5.0 'module' object is not iterable when running django website to the server

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, web, django-models

So i'm gonna run my Django project with **python manage.py runserver** but suddenly there comes an error like these:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ITHB MIT\TUGAS AKHIR\PRACTICE\program\Django Application\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 590, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\ITHB MIT\TUGAS AKHIR\PRACTICE\program\Django Application\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\ITHB MIT\TUGAS AKHIR\PRACTICE\program\Django Application\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "D:\ITHB MIT\TUGAS AKHIR\PRACTICE\program\Django Application\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "D:\ITHB MIT\TUGAS AKHIR\PRACTICE\program\Django Application\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "D:\ITHB MIT\TUGAS AKHIR\PRACTICE\program\Django Application\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "D:\ITHB MIT\TUGAS AKHIR\PRACTICE\program\Django Application\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "D:\ITHB MIT\TUGAS AKHIR\PRACTICE\program\Django Application\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "D:\ITHB MIT\TUGAS AKHIR\PRACTICE\program\Django Application\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\ITHB MIT\TUGAS AKHIR\PRACTICE\program\Django Application\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 597, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'project_settings.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

And there is my project.settings.urls

> ```
> """project_settings URL Configuration
> """
> from django.contrib import admin
> from django.urls import path, include
>
> from django.conf import settings
> from django.conf.urls.static import static
>
> urlpatterns = [
>     path('', include('ml_app.urls')),
> ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
> ```

And here are my **ml_app.urls**

```
        """project_settings URL Configuration """ 
from django.contrib import admin 
from django.urls import path, include 
from . import views 
from .views import about, index, predict_page,cuda_full
        
        app_name = 'ml_app' handler404 = views.handler404
        
        urlpatterns = [
            path('', index, name='home'),
            path('about/', about, name='about'),
            path('predict/', predict_page, name='predict'),
            path('cuda_full/',cuda_full,name='cuda_full'), 
    ]
```

Does someone know how to fix that error? It's pretty important for my final test =(

Comment: can I see your models.py and views.py?

Answer (score 0):

You have some circular imports. It means you have probably used imports from A to B, and then from B to A. You have to check dependencies. Sometime if you use a funtion, that imports model, and later you imports same function to that model, it would import infinitely. Check it in your code. Btw. don't import `views` and then every `View` from that `views` in the same file. It might be confusing

```
from django.contrib import admin 
from django.urls import path, include 
from ml_app.views import about, index, predict_page,cuda_full, handler404
```

Check [this article](https://www.alpharithms.com/django-circular-imports-153910/) to read more about issue.

Comment: Thank yout for the answer, but after i changed it and try to not use viewsa too many time. Nothing happened and still in the same error :(

Comment: Do you have your `urlpatterns` intended in your code like you have in here? Cause it should be leftmost. Same with `appname`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your app urls.py should be somethings like this:

```
        """project_settings URL Configuration """ 
from django.contrib import admin 
from django.urls import path, include  
from your-app-name import views  
        
        app_name = 'ml_app' handler404 = views.handler404
        
        urlpatterns = [
            path('', views.index, name='home'),
            path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
            path('predict/', views.predict_page, name='predict'),
            path('cuda_full/',views.cuda_full,name='cuda_full'), 
    ]
```

Comment: Hi thank your for answering, but i try it and nothing happened.